# Why is my multi-level inheritance mapping not working as I would expect it to?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have the following entity mappings:

```
// user.cfc
component persistent="true" table="user" discriminatorColumn="userTypeID" {

    property name="id" column="userID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
    property name="type" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="userType" fkcolumn="userTypeID";

}

// admin.cfc
component extends="user" persistent="true" table="admin" joincolumn="userID" discriminatorValue="3" {

    property name="id" column="adminID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";

}

// employee.cfc
component extends="user" persistent="true" table="employee" joincolumn="userID" discriminatorValue="0" {

    property name="id" column="employeeID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";

}

// manager.cfc
component extends="employee" persistent="true" table="manager" joincolumn="employeeID" discriminatorValue="1" {

    property name="id" column="managerID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";

}

// intern.cfc
component extends="employee" persistent="true" table="intern" joincolumn="employeeID" discriminatorValue="2" {

    property name="id" column="internID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";

}
```

Per Henry's suggestion, here are the generated hbmxml files:

```
<!-- user.hbmxml -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="user" lazy="true"
        name="cfc:user" table="user">
        <id name="ID" type="int">
            <column name="userID"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="userTypeID"/>
        <many-to-one class="cfc:userType"
            column="userTypeID" insert="false" name="type" update="false"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<!-- admin.hbmxml -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass discriminator-value="3" entity-name="admin"
        extends="cfc:user" lazy="true" name="cfc:admin">
        <join table="admin">
            <key column="userID"/>
        </join>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>


<!-- employee.hbmxml -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass discriminator-value="0" entity-name="employee"
        extends="cfc:user" lazy="true" name="cfc:employee">
        <join table="employee">
            <key column="userID"/>
        </join>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>


<!-- manager.hbmxml -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass discriminator-value="1" entity-name="manager"
        extends="cfc:employee" lazy="true" name="cfc:manager">
        <join table="manager">
            <key column="employeeID"/>
        </join>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>


<!-- intern.hbmxml -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass discriminator-value="2" entity-name="intern"
        extends="cfc:employee" lazy="true" name="cfc:intern">
        <join table="intern">
            <key column="employeeID"/>
        </join>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If it's not clear from the mappings, the relationships are as follows:

```
user
 |- admin
 |- employee
  |- manager
  |- intern
```

The intention is for the `type` property on the `user` entity to be populated by the discriminator value of the `manager` and `intern` entities. There is code in `employee`'s constructor that keeps it from being instantiated directly, so a `user` will always have a `type`.

The entire mapping works fine when reading some already-existing data from the DB. However, I run into problems when I attempt to insert a new record.

Assume that the tables involved already have some records populated:

```
user
|---------------------|
| userID | userTypeID |
|---------------------|
| 1      | 1          |
| 2      | 2          |
| 3      | 2          |
| 4      | 3          |
|---------------------|

admin
|------------------|
| adminID | userID |
|------------------|
| 1       | 4      |
|------------------|

employee
|---------------------|
| employeeID | userID |
|---------------------|
| 1          | 1      |
| 2          | 2      |
| 3          | 3      |
|---------------------|

manager
|------------------------|
| managerID | employeeID |
|------------------------|
| 1         | 1          |
|------------------------|

intern
|-----------------------|
| internID | employeeID |
|-----------------------|
| 1        | 2          |
| 2        | 3          |
|-----------------------|
```

If I were to create a new `intern` entity and persist it, I would expect three records to be inserted:

```
INSERT user ( userID, userTypeID ) VALUES ( 5, 2 )
INSERT employee ( employeeID, userID ) VALUES ( 4, 5 )
INSERT intern ( internID, employeeID ) VALUES ( 3, 4 )
```

However, the SQL that actually gets executed is as follows:

```
INSERT user ( userID, userTypeID ) VALUES ( 5, 2 )
INSERT employee ( employeeID, userID ) VALUES ( 4, 5 )
INSERT intern ( internID, employeeID ) VALUES ( 3, 5 ) -- using the new userID instead of the new employeeID
```

Finally, the actual question:

Why, when inserting into `intern`, is it using the `userID` instead of the `employeeID`? It's as if Hibernate is ignoring the `joincolumn` property on `intern` and just using the `joincolumn` from `employee`.

Comment: in order for hibernate guys to help you, you may want to consider posting the `.hbxml` CF generated.

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe that's how hibernate works.  They have their reasons behind this.  So either drink the koolaid and stay with what they give you, or simplify your design.

Comment: @Henry - Just to clarify, by "that's how hibernate works," you mean that you believe it is intended that hibernate ignores the join column beyond the first level of inheritance?

Comment: yup. Hibernate will use the discriminatorColumn in the User table to construct an "intern" so it uses userID.

Comment: @Henry - I did a little more experimentation and it looks like you are correct. If you'd like to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate will use the discriminatorColumn in the User table to construct an "intern" object so it uses userID rather than employeeID.